# Remove CNAME after Azure has verified the domain

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record

Once I have verified my domain in Azure with the CNAME record (with awverify), can I remove the CNAME record (awverify) safely from my DNS server without breaking anything?

Comment: Why would you want to do that and risk having an issue?  Is there a business need?

Comment: We have multiple subdomains, and I need the subdomains to go to one app service and the naked domain to go to another app service. Therefor I can't add 2 cname records that are both awverify.example.com that point to different azure app services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWVerify record is only used at the time you add the the hostname to your resource in Azure, after that it is no longer required and can be removed.

Comment: I know this is true, but do you of any places in the docs that tells me this?